# How do I permanently stop the attempt to add AssemblyInfo.cs and WebMenu.csproj to TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015

I was working on an old ASP.NET WebForms app, written years ago by people no longer around, in VB.NET. I prefer to use C#, but can do VB.NET. Anyway, I wanted to add a new project, named WebMenu, to the solution. I accidentally did so as a C# project, which I didn't realize until I tried to import of VB.NET files that needed to be included into this new project, but couldn't because I had made the mistake of creating the new project as a C# project.

So, I deleted the project from the solution, then got out of VS 2017, where I then deleted the WebMenu folder. After that, I got back into VS 2017, created the WebMenu project as a VB.NET project, and proceeded to include the already existing files into the new WebMenu project. All went well, until I tried to check in my changes to TFS. For some reason, either VS 2017 or TFS thinks that there's an AssemblyInfo.cs file and a WebMenu.csproj file in the WebMenu. It wants to add both to TFS. I can exclude them, when I check in the files, but the next time I want to check in files I've modified, both the AssemblyInfo.cs and WebMenu.csproj files appear in the Check-in tab for TFS. This has gotten to be very tedious.

So, how do I permanently make it so either VS 2017 or TFS 2015 will stop trying to add those two files to TFS?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Did you add an appropriate `.gitignore` or `.tfignore` file to your repository?

Comment: Good question, I'm sorry I didn't specify that. We're using TFVC.